# Embedded - DM3730 processor

Tags: embedded

I am referring the TRM of DM3730 and modifying the pad configurations on an EVM 3530 accordingly. I couldn't understand the following properly.

1) What are CORE power domain and WKUP power domain?

2) What is core control module and Wake-Up control module?

3) The above two questions may be completely hardware-oriented. But the reason I'm asking is, in EVM 3530 source code, in pad configurations, certain pins are defined as PAD_ENTRY and certain others as WKUP_PAD_ENTRY. What makes the difference?

```
#define PAD_ENTRY(x,y) {PAD_ID(x),y,0},
#define WKUP_PAD_ENTRY(x,y) {WKUP_PAD_ID(x),y,0},

#define I2C3_PADS \
PAD_ENTRY(I2C3_SCL, INPUT_ENABLED | PULL_RESISTOR_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0)) \
PAD_ENTRY(I2C3_SDA, INPUT_ENABLED | PULL_RESISTOR_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0)) 

#define I2C4_PADS \
WKUP_PAD_ENTRY(I2C4_SCL, INPUT_ENABLED | PULL_RESISTOR_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0)) \
WKUP_PAD_ENTRY(I2C4_SDA, INPUT_ENABLED | PULL_RESISTOR_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))
```

Any kind of guidance is welcome.

Comment: Likely the core power domain gets shut down in a power saving sleep mode, while the wakeup domain continues to power the circuitry which could wake it up again.  As for the mystery macros, try a recursive grep on the system includes and figure out where they are defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WKUP provides functions for sections of the OMAP SoC to come out of power-saving mode.

A power domain can be turned on/off without affecting others (4.1.3.2). WKUP power domain is continously active, it allows for switching others. CORE power domain comprises interconnect / memory / peripheral core functions.

Wake-up control module and core control module provide for save and restore of pad configurations (7.3) when switched off.

It looks like the pads which can be configured as I2C4 SCL/SDA can also be configured with wakeup capabilities. Then in your code base (Windows CE 6 BSP?) a different macro from generic PAD_ENTRY is appropriate, probably there is an error check of (x) to confirm pad ID is valid. The non-wakeup-related macro parameters should work the same for you, there won't be a difference.

Section references are to [OMAP35x-TRM](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruf98x/spruf98x.pdf).

Comment: So, do both the Wake-up control module and Core control module save pad configurations when switched off? Also, what kind of signals come under each domain?

Comment: Yes, both the Wake-up control module and Core control module save pad configurations. For "what kind of signals" you can refer to OMAP35x-TRM Table 7-4 (p. 773-780) for Core and Table 7-6 (p. 782-783). I suggest you consider accepting the answer to this question, then formulate and post another question after you have researched the topic in OMAP35x-TRM.